# Amplify AC signal only

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, signal

I amplify a signal which including AC and DC.Why is the output waveform changed when C1 is 0.1u?And how to decide the value of C1?
[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79153/calculating-the-value-of-bypass-capacitors-for-an-amplifier  this might help

Comment: Did U understand anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Capacitor Reactive Impedance, Xc(f) rises to affect impedance ratio with R such that they are equal, you can measure many responses;

1. the voltage amplitude divider ratio (gain) reduces times
   \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt(1+1)} = 0.707 = -3~dB\$
2. the current phase shift changes by 45 deg, (=trig. angle with equal sides of
   impedance)  which as already started  to shift with 0.1uF  that
   raises the impedance of Xc(f) to 26.5 kohm
3. the -3dB breakpoint is \$ω_1=1/(R_1C_1)=2\pi f\$
4. you can visualize all of this with a log impedance RLC nomograph and measure the impedance ratio of any XL(f) or C(f) vs V as the division ratio becomes a difference on a log scale. like 1000 is a difference of 3 decades
5. R+ C Series Impedance = \$Zc(f)=R+jXc(f)\$

   6. Also with this you can "ballpark" estimate corner frequencies and LC resonant circuits and Q gain factors for LC intersections with R differences (Ratios). 
      e.g. L//C//R is high impedance
      so $$Q_p=R/X_L(f)=R/X_C(f)$$
   7. at LC value intersection (=resonant f)
      then series resonant f (L+C+R)  $$Q_s=\frac{X_L(f)}{R}=\frac{X_C(f)}{R}$$  (using absolute values or ignoring phase due to j

   Here is one  example of the RLC Impedance nomograph.

[image]

Comment: sorry for the late reply.if i want to avoid attenuation and phase shift,the impendance of capacitor must be very lower than 47k.is that right?

Comment: Usually  1 or 2 decade below @ f http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+4+2741.96432338727%0Ac+192+80+352+80+0+1e-7+0%0Ar+352+80+352+208+0+47000%0AO+352+80+464+80+0%0Ag+352+208+352+240+0%0A170+192+80+160+80+3+20+1000+5+0.1%0Ao+4+16+0+34+5+0.00009765625+0+-1+in%0Ao+2+16+0+34+2.5+0.00009765625+1+-1+out%0A

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/umlnwmo