# Thin film capacitor for voltage multiplier

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, high-frequency, high-speed, voltage-doubler

I am designing a voltage multiplier with 5 to 10 stages. I have this circuit where I run a transformer at 450KHz and feed the output to the voltage multiplier. Is it a good idea to use thin film capacitor?

I have it lying around and also super cheap when compared to ceramic capacitors of same rating.

[Name of the capacitor used(ECW-FG2J155Q1)](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Panasonic/ECW-FG2J155Q1?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsh%252B1woXyUXj4CFOnAa7QYs44t8BQRKhhI%3D)

Lets say I am making a 10 stage voltage multiplier (Cockcroft-Walton half wave multiplier) which runs at 450KHz with 250V fed to the multiplier, I should be getting 5KV as output. Is this a good choice of capacitor? I am worried about the derating at higher frequencies.

Comment: Why does your hyperlink anchor text say "Name of the capacitor used" instead of the name of the capacitor used?

Comment: You are making some bad assumptions like 450kHz with 500V is a good idea and 1.5uF is a good load for that frequency.  Go compare your transformer and source impedance to the impedance of the cap. What do you see? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475533/amplify-ac-signal-only/475554#475554

Comment: I am unable to determine the transformer impedance as it is attached. It is driven by an H-bridge driver IC which gives a square wave output of 5V peak to peak. I think its a MAX13256 connected to a 5V 5A boost regulator. As for the impedance of the Capacitor, I am guessing that would be 0.2497 Ohm/cap (Calculated using 1/2x3.14xfxC) Since this is connected in series, a 10 stage would have 2.4Ohm on top cap and 2.4 ohm bottom cap. I think it might be a 12VA transformer. (Guess)