# Inductor under variable voltage source

Tags: voltage, analog, inductor

In order to understand a tank circuit , I need to understand how inductors behave under differential voltage(discharging capacitor).I know inductors in AC behave like resistors but I don't know how exactly.
How does an inductor behave under the pressence of a differential voltage?

Comment: Impedance L increases with frequency or risetime just the opposite of caps.   The intersection where | impedances | are equal is where they resonate and R ratio determines damping factor or inversely Q gain.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475533/amplify-ac-signal-only/475554?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C29.9484#475554

Answer (score 1):

Inductors behave like this:

$$V_L = L \frac{dI_L}{dt}$$

You should be able to get whatever you need from that.

Comment: @ElliotAnderson I don't want a mathematical expression I want to understand the intuition behind LC oscillations.

Comment: Maybe you need to show us the specific circuit of interest. Your original question is pretty broad.

Answer (score 0):

In a tank circuit, you have a situation where an inductor and capacitor are exchanging energy; the capacitor will discharge into the inductor, the inductor will charge up the capacitor, repeat.  Since there are parasitic resistance in the circuit (and parasitic capacitances and inductances), the oscillations will eventually die out unless additional energy is supplied by an external driving waveform.  At a specific frequency, the impedances of the capacitance and inductance are equal in magnitude but opposite in sign and certain interesting things can happen.